# Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. **_Pnext** было 0x15534A4., произошло

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему выводиться ошибка указанная в теме?

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


struct User_log
{
    char user_name[25];
    char user_password[25];
    unsigned long int group=0;
};
vector <string> vuserlog;
vector <string> vuserpassword;
vector <int> vgroup;
struct Info_bd
{
    string  phone;
    string FIO;
    int type_call;
    string phone_in;
    int day;
    int month;
    int yers;
    double time_speaking;
    double tariff;
};
vector <string> vFIO;
vector <string> vphone;
vector <int> vtype_call;
vector <string> vphone_in;
vector <int> vday;
vector <int> vmonth;
vector <int> vyears;
vector <double> vtime_speaking;
vector <double> vtariff;

void setInfo_bd(Info_bd& info_bd)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << " Количество абонентов:";
    int col_inf=0;
    cin >> col_inf;
    vector<Info_bd> vinfo_bd(col_inf);
    /*ofstream fout("account.txt", ostream::binary);//инициализация потока файла
    //Заполнение труктуры
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        cout << " User name:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].user_name;
        cout << " Password:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].user_password;
        cout << " Group:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].group;
    }*/
    //Запись
    ofstream InfoOut("info_bd_call.txt", ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i < col_inf; ++i)
    {
        /*inoff
            << vuser_log[i].user_name
            << " "
            << vuser_log[i].user_password
            << " "
            << vuser_log[i].group
            << "\n";*/
        cout << "ФИО:";
        cin >> info_bd.FIO;
        cout << "Номер телефона:";
        cin >> info_bd.phone;
        cout << "Тип звонка(Входящий - 1, исходящий 0):";
        cin >> info_bd.type_call;
        cout << "Номер входящего телефона:";
        cin >> info_bd.phone_in;
        cout << "Дата звонка:"; 
        cin >> info_bd.day; cout << "."; cin >> info_bd.month; cout << "."; cin >> info_bd.yers;
        cout << "Продолжительнотьт разговора(мин.):";
        cin >> info_bd.time_speaking;
        cout << "Тариф:";
        cin >> info_bd.tariff;
        InfoOut.write((char*)&info_bd, sizeof(Info_bd));
    }
    InfoOut.close();
}
void setInfo(User_log& user_log)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    cout << " Количество пользователей:";
    int col=0;
    cin >> col;
    vector<User_log> vuser_log(col);
    /*ofstream fout("account.txt", ostream::binary);//инициализация потока файла
    //Заполнение труктуры
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        cout << " User name:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].user_name;
        cout << " Password:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].user_password;
        cout << " Group:"; cin >> vuser_log[i].group;
    }*/
    //Запись
    ofstream inoff("account.txt", ios::out);
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
    {
        /*inoff
            << vuser_log[i].user_name
            << " "
            << vuser_log[i].user_password
            << " "
            << vuser_log[i].group
            << "\n";*/
        cout << "Введите логин:";
        cin >> user_log.user_name;
        cout << "Пароль:";
        cin >> user_log.user_password;
        cout << "Группа:";
        cin >> user_log.group;
        inoff.write((char*)&user_log, sizeof(User_log));
    }
    //inoff.write((char*)&user_log, sizeof(User_log));
    inoff.close();
}

void readAllUser_accObj(vector <User_log> vUser_log)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    User_log user_log;
    ifstream fin("account.txt");
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.read((char*)&user_log, sizeof(User_log));
        vUser_log.push_back(user_log);
    }
    fin.close();
}

void getInfo(User_log& user_log)
{
    memset(&user_log, 0, sizeof(User_log));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int i = 0;
    int vcout = 0;

    ifstream fin("account.txt", ios::in);
    while (true)
    {
        fin.read((char*)&user_log, sizeof(User_log));
        //cout << user_log.user_name << " ";
        vuserlog.push_back(user_log.user_name);
        //cout << user_log.user_password << " ";
        vuserpassword.push_back(user_log.user_password);
        //cout << user_log.group << " ";
        vgroup.push_back(user_log.group);
        vcout++;
        if(fin.peek() == EOF) break;
    }
    fin.close();
    /*for (int p = 0; p < vuserlog.size(); p++)
    {
        cout << vuserlog[p];
        cout << vuserpassword[p];
        cout << vgroup[p];
    }*/
    /*cout << "Поиск по имени:" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j <= vuserlog.size(); j++)
    {
        if (vuserlog[j] == nameu)
            cout << "Совпало:" << vuserlog[j] << endl;
    }*/
}
void getInfo_bd(Info_bd& info_bd){
    memset(&info_bd, 0, sizeof(Info_bd));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int i = 0;
    ifstream Ifin("info_bd_call.txt", ios::in);
    while (true)
    {
        Ifin.read((char*)&info_bd, sizeof(Info_bd));
        vFIO.push_back(info_bd.FIO);
        vphone.push_back(info_bd.phone);
        vtype_call.push_back(info_bd.type_call);
        vphone_in.push_back(info_bd.phone_in);
        vday.push_back(info_bd.day);
        vmonth.push_back(info_bd.month);
        vyears.push_back(info_bd.yers);
        vtime_speaking.push_back(info_bd.time_speaking);
        vtariff.push_back(info_bd.tariff);
        if (Ifin.peek() == EOF) break;
    }
    Ifin.close();

}
void searchNmaeinBd(string s_name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vFIO.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vFIO[i]==s_name)
        {
            cout << "Найде фамилия:" << vFIO[i] << vphone[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
void AllInf()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vFIO.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Фамилия:" << vFIO[i] << endl;
        cout << " номер телефона:" << vphone[i] << endl;
        cout << " тип звонка(входящий - 1, исходящий - 0):" << vtype_call[i] << endl;
        cout << " номер входящего:" << vphone_in[i] << endl;
        cout << " дата звонка:" << vday[i] << "." << vmonth[i] << "." << vyears[i] << endl;
        cout << " время разговора(мин):" << vtime_speaking[i] << endl;
        cout << " стоимсоть тарифа:" << vtariff[i] << " руб." << endl;
    }
    vFIO.shrink_to_fit();
    vphone.shrink_to_fit();
    vtype_call.shrink_to_fit();
    vphone_in.shrink_to_fit();
    vday.shrink_to_fit();
    vmonth.shrink_to_fit();
    vyears.shrink_to_fit();
    vtime_speaking.shrink_to_fit();
    vtariff.shrink_to_fit();
}
void ScreenInfo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vFIO.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Фамилия:" << vFIO[i] << " номер телефона:" << vphone[i] << " тип звонка(входящий - 1, исходящий - 0):" << vtype_call[i] << " номер входящего:"
            << vphone_in[i] << " дата звонка:" << vday[i] << "." << vmonth[i] << "." << vyears[i] << " время разговора(мин):" << vtime_speaking[i] << " стоимсоть тарифа:" << vtariff[i] << " руб." << endl;
    }
}
void login_password(string lg, string pw)
{
    bool ok = false;
    while (!ok)
    {
        for (int ui = 0; ui < vuserlog.size(); ui++)
        {
            if (vuserlog[ui] == lg && vuserpassword[ui] == pw)
            {
                cout << "Добро пожаловать!" << endl;
                ok = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (ok != true) 
        {
            cout << "Лоигн:"; cin >> lg;
            cout << "Пароль:"; cin >> pw;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    User_log user_log;
    Info_bd info_bd;
    vector<User_log> vUser_log;
    char* name;
    int varian;
    string login;
    string password;
    cout << "Логин:";
    cin >> login;
    cout << "Пароль:";
    cin >> password;
    getInfo(user_log);
    login_password(login, password);
    cout << "1. Запсиь в файл" << endl;
    cout << "2. Чтение из файла" << endl;
    cout << "3. Добавить абонента" << endl;
    cout << "4. Информация об абонентах:" << endl;
    cout << "5. Найти по имени" << endl;
    cin >> varian;
    string un;
    switch (varian)
    {
    case 1: setInfo(user_log); break;
    case 2:
            {
            cout << "Какой ник необходимо найти:";
            cin >> un;
            //ScreenInfo(vUser_log, un);
        //cout << user_log.user_name << endl;
        //cout << user_log.user_password << endl;
        //cout << user_log.group << endl;
            break;
            }
    case 3: setInfo_bd(info_bd); break;
    case 4: 
            {
                getInfo_bd(info_bd);
                AllInf();
                break;
            }
    case 5: 
            {
                getInfo_bd(info_bd);
                string search_name;
                cin >> search_name;
                searchNmaeinBd(search_name);
                break;
            }
    default:"Такого в меню нет!";

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если закрыть глаза на все, что там есть, то самой вероятной ошибкой есть то, что Вы пытаетесь работать с структурой `Info_bd` как с pod типом. А там как минимум есть `std::string`. Попытка к такой структуре применить memset или чтение/запись по указателю практически 100% приведет к повреждению памяти. И после этого возможны и не такие сообщения об ошибках.

Что делать? либо начать писать на с++ и добавить структуре `Info_bd` корректные функции для очистки/чтения/записи, либо перейти на чистый си и отказаться от `std::string`. Выбирайте.